# PrimeFaces How to represent Label insted of value in p:datatable cells

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

hi every one I have this scenario :

i am using primefaces data table `p:datatable` and it receives a list from managed bean...
please look for this sample : and pay attention to the header "status"

```
<p:datatable styleClass="table1" id="listTable" var="t" value="{testBean.elements}">
    <p:column headerText="Request No.">
       <h:outputText value="#{t.part_request_no}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Request No.">
       <h:outputText value="#{t.part_request_date}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <!--please pay attention here -->
    <p:column headerText="status">
        <h:outputText value="#{t.part_status}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

the result looks like : this

```
Request No.  | Request Date | Status |
    1        |   2013-02-02 |   1    |
    2        |   2013-01-01 |   2    |
    3        |  2013-4-23   |   5    |
```

my Question is : representing 1, 2, 5 is a shame. so i prefer to view statuses like

- 1 : New
- 2 : Rejected
- 5 : Canceled.

**the result i require to be like this**

```
Request No.  | Request Date | Status   |
    1        |   2013-02-02 |   New    |
    2        |   2013-01-01 | Rejected |
    3        |   2013-4-23  | Canceled |
```

any ideas ????
thank you ....

Comment: display the field with name? how should WE know what YOUR objects have?

Comment: I don't think this transformation should be done in presentation layer of application, but rather in business logic. Use `eunum` or constants or create database table to hold this mapping.

Comment: aha ....  i know about using the database and managed bean but i thought there are solution in primefaces ....thanks for your answer parlov ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways depending on how and where you'd like to maintain the mapping between status codes and associated descriptions.

1. Hardcoded in view.

   ```html
   <h:outputText value="New" rendered="#{t.part_status == 1}" />
   <h:outputText value="Rejected" rendered="#{t.part_status == 2}" />
   <h:outputText value="Cancelled" rendered="#{t.part_status == 5}" />
   ```

   ---
2. Hardcoded in a map.

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class Data {

       private static final Map<Long, String> STATUSES = createStatuses();

       private static Map<Long, String> createStatuses() {
           Map<Long, String> statuses = new HashMap<Long, String>();
           statuses.put(1L, "New");
           statuses.put(2L, "Rejected");
           statuses.put(5L, "Cancelled");
           return Collections.unmodifiableMap(statuses);
       }

       public Map<Long, String> getStatuses() {
           return STATUSES;
       }

   }
   ```

   with

   ```html
   <h:outputText value="#{data.statuses[t.part_status]}" />
   ```

   ---
3. Definied in a loclaized resource bundle file.

   ```
   status.1 = New
   status.2 = Rejected
   status.5 = Cancelled
   ```

   with

   ```html
   <f:loadBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" var="text" />
   ...
   <c:set var="statusKey" value="status.#{t.part_status}" />
   <h:outputText value="#{text[statusKey]}" />
   ```

   ---
4. Definied in an enum.

   ```
   public enum Status {

       New(1), Rejected(2), Cancelled(5);

       private int code;

       private Status(int code) {
           this.code = code;
       }

       public static Status of(int code) {
           for (Status status : values()) {
               if (status.code == code) {
                   return status;
               }
           }
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       }

       public int getCode() { 
           return code;
       }

   }
   ```

   and during populating the model

   ```
   t.setPart_status(Status.of(statusCode));
   ```

   and then just in the view

   ```html
   <h:outputText value="#{t.part_status}" />
   ```

   ---

A combination can also. E.g. i18n label in enum.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd work on your [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). `part_status` is not a valid property name. It should be `partStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just simply create a method in you ManagedBean to convert it to the label you want?

```
<p:column headerText="status">
    <h:outputText value="#{testBean.getStatusLabel(t.part_status)}"/>
</p:column>
```

And on the ManagedBean:

```
public String getStatusLabel(int code){
    // Do your thing here...
}
```